# Drag And Drop Site Builder That Takes User Input and Displays It On The Site

Tags: images, website

I am looking for a drag and drop online site builder that takes user input (a couple of text boxes and an image upload) and then displays it on the website. I would also like the users to be able to have their own accounts. Is there any sort of online tool that can do this sort of thing? Or do I need to write custom PHP, Java, etc code. Thanks.

```
Basic Workflow
1) user logs in website
2) user fills out a form consisting of a textfield and an image upload
3) user submits the information using a button
4) information is posted on website for others to see
5) user is able to make changes to their input anytime
```

I know I can use online form builders such as Wufoo, Zoho, etc to collect user input, but I don't know of a way to actually display that input on the site itself (for the public to see)....as well as give the user the ability modify their postings at a later time. Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Comment: but I did describe my situation in the "Basic Workflow" section...

Comment: Yes, but you're broadly describing what you want in a product or service, not an actual computer problem you'd like help with.  Perhaps look into [Image Hosting Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_hosting_service), and [Content Management Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a Content Management System. There are free open-source CMS systems you can install.

By what you're desribing, a blog system might work too. Here's my list of suggestions:

```
1. Wordpress (blog system with easy update system and installing addons using 
   the website)
2. Joomla (CMS system with many options, update maintainance is required by 
   the user on regular basis)
3. Drupal (CMS system with many options, update maintainance is required by 
   the user on regular basis)
```

As stated by techie007, this post is higly suggestive and opiion-based. My goal here is to give you a push in the right direction so you can make the choice for yourself. If you want a better solution, try being more specific in your post.